# OnClick listener does not work after rotate ImageView?

Tags: android, android-imageview

I am using the below code to rotate an ImageView Control

```
ImageView Iv = new this.findViewById(id)
RotateAnimation a = new RotateAnimation(0, 60);
a.setFillAfter(true);
a.setFillBefore(false);
a.setDuration(0);
Iv.startAnimation(a);
```

The problem with the above code is that the ImageView looks rotated, but can't be clicked correctly. The coordinates that trigger the click event are the ones at the area the control had before beeing rotated.

Also I tried another solution,, I tried to write a custom view extends ImageView and rotate the control canvas in onDraw() but this solution did not rotate the control , it rotates the content of the control.

```
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas)
{
canvas.rotate(60, getWidth() / 2, getHeight() / 2);
super.onDraw(canvas);
canvas.save();
canvas.restore();
}

@Override
protected synchronized void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
super.onMeasure(heightMeasureSpec, widthMeasureSpec);
setMeasuredDimension(getMeasuredHeight(), getMeasuredWidth());
}
```

any idea how can I rotate the control itself and keep it clickable ?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Animation doesn't change your views position. It's a common issue with animation. Please look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10443146/button-not-responding-to-click-event-after-translation-animation).

Comment: I got you, but my case is different than your link , since I am changing the control rotation not the control position ,, is there any work around to solve this issue, I need it urgently,, thanks

Comment: But the issue is still the same - this problem is with any animation (which doesn't keep state after animation) and not especially with moving objects. The easiest way to handle your probem (but not very nice) whould be putting two imageViews: one before animation and second one after animation (invisible). After rotating first image just make it invisible and second one visible(in onAnimationEnd method).