# Touch targets do not move with object when using translate animation?

Tags: android, android-animation, android-transitions

Whenever I use `TranslateAnimation` to move an object to a new location, for some reason, the touch target of that object remains in the old position.

How do I change this behaviour?

eg.

```
public static void hideViewUp (View v, int duration) {

            AnimationSet animSet = new AnimationSet(true);
            animSet.setFillAfter(true);
            animSet.setDuration(duration);
            AlphaAnimation alp = new AlphaAnimation(1.0f, 0);
            TranslateAnimation translate = new TranslateAnimation(Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF,
                    Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF,
                    Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF,
                    -(v.getTop() + v.getHeight()));
            animSet.addAnimation(translate);
            animSet.addAnimation(alp);
            v.startAnimation(animSet);

    }
```

Comment: In order to help others understand your issue, please post a sample of code, outputs of any logs (e.g. LogCat) or something to demonstrate a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your problem.

Comment: @EdGeorge This is a quite general issue and not code or implementation dependant.

Comment: You should still show your code to demonstrate what you are doing

Comment: Possible answer - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10443146/button-not-responding-to-click-event-after-translation-animation

Answer (score 0):

There's no need to post any sample code - the issue is indeed pretty well known and general.

TranslateAnimation and all other old types of animation change only the draw transformation matrix. These animations shouldn't be used to move items permamently.

To truly move a view to a new position, use ObjectAnimator.

Here's an example: http://www.android-app-market.com/animations-in-android-translate-animation-alpha-animation-object-animation.html