# Android Animated ImageView click event

Tags: android, image, animated

I'll keep this short and to the point, How would I detect when a animated ImageView is clicked?

Right now I use the code below and it is triggered when I click the left top corner... because that's where the picture is before its animated.

```
    ImageView img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.bubble1);
    img.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
          start();
        }});
```

Comment: This might help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10443146/button-not-responding-to-click-event-after-translation-animation/11013633#11013633

Comment: Close, but that topic is to click the image after its done moving. I want to click the image while its moving.

Comment: Could you just use a `ViewPropertyAnimator`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, my bet would be for you to use `ontouch()`.

Try something like the following.

```
@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event){
        switch(event.getAction())
        {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP :
            {
                // Do whatever you want here.
            }
        return true;
}
```

Comment: Yes that would work, but I would need to write an equation to calculate where the image is based on screen height and animation duration. I guess I'll do that. Thank you.

Comment: You're very welcome my friend. Glad to help. Good luck!

Comment: For anyone that would like to know: here is the formula I came up with: Y = Height / Duration * (StartTime - CurentTime)  This will only work for animated images moving from Y=0 to the top, You can replace Height With width for Left to Right. It causes a little lag because I'm running the whole formula 6 times every time I click... But it works :D