# After translating a view, the area where you press to trigger a button press doesn't move. How do you move this area with the view?

Tags: android, android-animation

I created a button and wanted it to move to the bottom of the screen after some event is triggered. So I made an TranslateAnimation object

```
    private TranslateAnimation setupAnimation(float yOffset) {
    TranslateAnimation animation = new TranslateAnimation(0, 0, 0, yOffset);
    animation.setDuration(1000);
    animation.setFillAfter(true);
    animation.setInterpolator(new AccelerateDecelerateInterpolator());
    return animation;
}
```

Then I pass in the TranslateAnimation object into the startAnimation() method of the view I wanted to move.

Well that works for what I want to accomplish visually, but I noticed that I can't click on where it is visibly, but I can press where the button used to be and the onClick callback will be executed.

What do I need to do, post translation, to allow the user to press the button at its new location?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Button not responding to Click Event after Translation animation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10443146/button-not-responding-to-click-event-after-translation-animation)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A TranslateAnimation only moves the pixels on the screen, it does not change the actual position of your Button, it just looks like it is moving, so your OnClick/OnTouchListener will not animate with it.

Use ObjectAnimator or ViewPropertyAnimator to really change the property of your Button.

Here is an example using [ViewPropertyAnimator](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewPropertyAnimator.html) to get you started :

```
yourButton.animate()
    .translationY(yOffset)
    .setInterpolator(new AccelerateDecelerateInterpolator())
    .setDuration(1000);
```

check the [Docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewPropertyAnimator.html) for other available methods.