# ObjectAnimator with Infinite rotation stutters

Tags: java, android, animation, android-animation, objectanimator

I have an animator, `infinite_rotation`, defined as:

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <objectAnimator
        android:propertyName="rotation"
        android:repeatCount="infinite"
        android:valueFrom="0"
        android:valueTo="360"
        android:duration="2000" />
</set>
```

When the time (time is indefinite) comes that I no longer need this, I call `infinite_animator.cancel()`. Then play a **fade_out** animation on its layout container:

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <objectAnimator
            android:propertyName="alpha"
            android:repeatCount="0"
            android:valueTo="0.0"
            android:duration="1000" />
</set>
```

The resulting animation is that, the rotation stops as expected but stutters while fading out. What am I missing?

Here is how it looks:

[image]

UPDATE: 
I was testing the above problem on old Samsung Tab 4 with Kitkat OS. I just tested on a fairly newer Samsung Tab 4 with Marshmallow OS. The animation works fine. So I guess the better question is how do I fix the sloppy animation on my older device/OS?

This is the animation call:

```
private void animateRefreshButton() {
    ImageView iv_refresh = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iv_refresh);

    if(infinite_animator == null) {
        infinite_animator = AnimatorInflater.loadAnimator(this, R.animator.refresh_rotate);
    }
    infinite_animator.setTarget(iv_refresh);
    infinite_animator.start();
}
```

`hideRefreshButton()` is initiated when the app determines refresh is complete. This is the call to cancel and fade out animation:

```
private void hideRefreshButton() {
    if(infinite_animator != null) {
        infinite_animator.cancel();
    }

    Animator anim = AnimatorInflater.loadAnimator(this, R.animator.refresh_fadeout);
    anim.addListener(new Animator.AnimatorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animator animation) {}

        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
            framelayout_container_of_iv_refresh.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationCancel(Animator animation) {}

        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animator animation) {}
    });
    anim.setTarget(framelayout_container_of_iv_refresh);
    anim.start();
}
```

Comment: Did you try to set fillAfter to true for your rotation animation?

Comment: no. i can try that out. thanks.

Comment: Can you post a gif of that behavior?

Comment: yes sure. i will post the gif today.

Comment: @algrid i think setFillAfter is for View Animation only (?). I am using Property Animation.

Comment: @azizbekian updated the question with gif in it

Comment: pls add the code where you start and stop the respective animations.

Comment: @iMDroid i added the requested code

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Personally I do not use [Animation API](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/view-animation.html) because of the ["problems" it has](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10443189/1083957). Instead, I would go with [Animators API](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/animation/Animator.html) in this case.

Have this snippet:

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        View view = findViewById(R.id.imageView);

        ObjectAnimator objectAnimator = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(view, View.ROTATION, 0.0f, 360.0f);

        objectAnimator.setDuration(2000);
        objectAnimator.setRepeatCount(Animation.INFINITE);
        objectAnimator.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());

        objectAnimator.addListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationCancel(Animator animation) {
                view.animate()
                        .alpha(0.0f)
                        .setDuration(1000);
            }
        });

        objectAnimator.start();

        view.setOnClickListener((v) -> objectAnimator.cancel());

    }
```

Then this will be the output:

[image]

---

I've tested on emulator (API 19): works as expected.

Comment: I am using ObjectAnimator as well. In my case, I created the animator thru an xml resource.

Comment: @user1506104, now I see, sorry for confusion.

Comment: @user1506104, can you show how are you starting and canceling your animation, so that we understand why your code works that way?

Comment: no worries (+1 still for sharing your idea) ... before i share the code, please see the updated question.

Comment: @user1506104, emulator with API 19 runs the animations as expected. Can you confirm that the code I have shared also stutters?

Comment: yes this works. but I should apply the fadeout effect on its container, a RelativeLayout

Comment: Is that a problem? Instead of `view.animate().alpha(0.0f).setDuration(1000)` perform `relativeLayout.animate().alpha(0.0f).setDuration(1000)`

Comment: yeah i think thats the problem. I tried to remove the layout, the fade out works fine on the image view.